# How to save every object inside an array using for loop in parse.com + AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I am using AngularJS and Parse.com. I want to save all of the objects inside an array.
But why not all elements on the array are save?

```
var ActivityContact = Parse.Object.extend("ActivityContact");
var ActivityContactObject = new ActivityContact();

var count = $scope.addContList.length;
if(count > 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        $scope.addContList[i].activityId = actObj.id;
        ActivityContactObject.save( JSON.parse(
          angular.toJson($scope.addContList[i]))).then(function (ActContObj) {
            console.log("ActivityContact Saved - Object: ");
            console.dir(ActContObj);
        });
    }
}
```

This is what I get on the inspector:
https://db.tt/fDFuC83f

Only one element is save and then is update it.

+++

**Off topic**, but in case you know, is`JSON.parse(angular.toJson($scope.addContList[i]))` the only way to get rid of the `$$hashKey` injected by Angular?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it in this way, I don't know if this is the best method but it worked. I accept suggestions to improve it.

```
var ActivityContact = Parse.Object.extend("ActivityContact");
var list = [];
var count = $scope.addContList.length;
if(count > 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var ActivityContactObject = new ActivityContact();
        $scope.addContList[i].activityId = actObj.id;
        ActivityContactObject.set(JSON.parse(angular.toJson($scope.addContList[i])));
        list.push(ActivityContactObject);
    }
    Parse.Object.saveAll(list).then(function(results){
        console.log("Objects were saved!");
    },function(eerror){
        console.log(eerror);
    });
}
```

off topic: I'm still wondering if this (JSON.parse(angular.toJson($scope.addContList[i]))) the best method to solve $$hashKey...